# How to search a SQL table according to pairs in an R data frame?

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, dbi

I'd like to check if a pair of columns in a data frame is present in a SQL table.
For example, in the SQL table, is person id 1 and job id 100 present in the SQL table (as a pair). The person needs to be linked to the job. How do I go about doing this? In my code below, I don't think the person is paired with their job. Any help would be appreciated. Also, this is using R and SQL Server.

| person_id | job_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 101 |
| 3 | 102 |
| 4 | 102 |

```
library(glue)
library(DBI)

data_to_check <- data.frame(person_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                           job_id = c(100, 101, 102, 102))

comparison <-
  dbGetQuery(conn = x,
             glue_sql(.con = x,
                      "SELECT * FROM TABLE
                      WHERE person_id IN ({data_to_check$person_id*}) 
                      AND job_id IN ({data_to_check$job_id*})"))

# I don't care if
# `job_id` 102 is simply present, for example. I want to see if the pairing of
# `person_id` as `3` and `job_id` `102` is present in `TABLE`. How do I search the 
# SQL table for the pairs in `data_to_check` ? I think what I currently have won't
# search according to id pairs.
```

Comment: Perhaps you can pass the whole dataframe as a Table Valued parameter and join it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing is to upload the frame into a temporary table then query against it with a left-join. For instance,

```r
dbWriteTable(x, "mytemp", data_to_check, create = TRUE, append = FALSE, temporary = TRUE)
ret <- dbGetQuery(x, "
  select t2.*
  from mydata t1
    left join TABLE t2 on t1.person_id = t2.person_id and t1.job_id = t2.job_id")
dbExecute(x, "drop table mytemp") # not technically required if a temp-table
```

The only caveat I'll throw out is that not all DBMSes deal with temp-tables in the same way. For instance, with SQL Server, the `DBI` package's `temporary=TRUE` does not work correctly, you need to name the table with a leading `#` (local-temp) or `##` (global-temp), and then use those `#`-led table names whenever you reference the table.

Comment: Any thoughts, HITHERE? Does this work in your use-case?

Comment: HITHERE, any progress? I think the answer addresses one (perhaps the only?) method to do what you need *efficiently*. If it works, please accept; if not, you're unlikely to get more help without updates and clarification.

Comment: Hello, HITHERE? You've been back to StackOverflow several times over the last month but have yet to provide any feedback. What's the issue? Does this work for you? If not, what warnings/errors do you get?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm new to this website. I tried this but ran into issues. I ended up loading data doing a SQL query in R and then an anti-join.

Comment: This would have worked, and I was using this. I clicked the check mark. I just found that doing another method worked with some other things I was doing in the project. Thanks!